# Sliding tile puzzle with varying tile size using logic programming

Tags: prolog, xsb

So I am trying to solve this Booth arrangement problem [given here](https://sites.google.com/site/prologcontest2017/problem-1). It is basically a sliding tile puzzle where one (booth)tile has to reach a target spot and in the end all other (booths)tiles should be in their original location. Each tile/booth has a dimension and following are the input fact and relation descriptions:

- One fact of the form room(W,H), which specifies the width W and
  height H of the room (3 ≤ W,  H ≤ 20).
- One fact booths(B), which
  specifies the number of booths (1 ≤ B ≤ 20).
- A relation that consists
  of facts of the form dimension(B, W, H), which specifies the width W 
  and height H of booth B.
- A relation consisting of facts of the form
  position(B, W, H), specifying the initial position (W, H) of booth B.
- One fact target(B, W, H), specifying the destination (W, H) of the
  target booth B.
- An additional fact horizon(H) gives an upper bound on
  the number of moves to be performed.

The program is supposed to read input facts from a file but I am just trying to do the solving so I have just copy pasted one possible input for now, and I have written some basic clauses:

```
room(3, 3).
booths(3).
dimension(1, 2, 1).
dimension(2, 2, 1).
dimension(3, 1, 1).
position(1, 0, 1).
position(2, 1, 2).
position(3, 0, 0).
target(3, 0, 2).
horizon(10).

xlim(X) :- room(X,_).
ylim(X) :- room(_,X).

sum(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X+Y .

do(position(B,X,Y),movedown,position(B,X,Z)) :- Y > 0 , sum(Y,-1,Z) .
do(position(B,X,Y),moveup,position(B,X,Z)) :- ylim(L), Y < L , sum(Y,1,Z) .
do(position(B,X,Y),moveleft,position(B,Z,Y)) :- X > 0 , sum(X,-1,Z) .
do(position(B,X,Y),moveright,position(B,Z,Y)) :- xlim(L), X < L, sum(X,1,Z) .

noverlap(B1,B2) :- 
    position(B1,X1,Y1), 
    position(B2,X2,Y2), 
    ends(Xe1,Ye1,B1), 
    ends(Xe2,Ye2,B2), 
    ( Xe1 < X2 ; 
      Xe2 < X1 ; 
      Ye1 < Y2 ; 
      Ye2 < Y1 ).

ends(Xe,Ye,B) :- 
    dimension(B,W,H), 
    position(B,X,Y), 
    Xe is X+W-1, 
    Ye is Y+H-1.

between(X,Y,Z) :- 
    X > Y , 
    X < Z .

validMove(M,B) :- do(position(B,X,Y),M,position(B,Xn,Yn)) .
```

I am new to Prolog and I am stuck on how to go from here, I have the no_overlap rule so I can test if a move is valid or not but I am not sure how with the current clauses that I have. My current clauses for moves do/3 probably needs some modification. Any pointers?.

Answer (score 7):

You need to express the task in terms of **relations between states** of the puzzle. Your current clauses determine the validity of a single move, and can also generate possible moves.

However, that is not sufficient: You need to express more than just a single move and its effect on a single tile. You need to encode, in some way, the *state* of the whole puzzle, and also encode how a single move changes the state of the whole task.

For a start, I recommend you think about a relation like:

```
world0_move_world(W0, M, W) :- ...
```

and express the relation between a given "world" `W0`, a possible move `M`, and the *resulting* world `W`. This relation should be so general as to *generate*, on backtracking, each move `M` that is possible in `W0`. Ideally, it should even work if `W0` is a free variable, and for this you may find [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) useful: Constraints allow you to express *arithmetic relations* in a much more general way than you are currently using.

Once you have such a relation, the whole task is to find a *sequence* `Ms` of moves *such that* any initial world `W0` is *transformed* to a desired state `W`.

Assuming you have implemented `world0_move_world/3` as a building block, you can easily lift this to *lists* of moves as follows (using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)):

```
moves(W0) --> { desired_world(W0) }.
moves(W0) --> [M], { world0_move_world(W0, M, W) }, moves(W).
```

You can then use *iterative deepening* to find a *shortest* sequence of moves that solves the puzzle:

```
?- length(Ms, _), initial_world(W0), phrase(moves(W0), Ms).
```

Comment: I am still a little confused as to how to represent state in this problem as the tile sizes are not fixed (input). I was thinking of using a list of lists but that won't work here.

Comment: That's completely OK: Choosing a good state representation is typically among the hard parts when solving such puzzles, and a good choice of representation can make your solution much easier to formulate, and also much more efficient. I suggest you take your time with this part, and consider a few possible ways to represent the placement of the tiles. For example, one way would be to keep track of some reference point for each tile, its orientation, and its shape etc. After some time, you may want to file a separate question for just this aspect, I think it would be nice to discuss it too.